# データフレームの拡張と補間

Tags: python, pandas

```
年月日時    気温(℃)   降水量(mm) 風速(m/s) 日射量(MJ/㎡)           
2017-01-01 00:00:00 5.8 0.0 1.5 0.0
2017-01-01 01:00:00 4.9 0.0 0.8 0.0
2017-01-01 02:00:00 4.9 0.0 1.5 0.0
2017-01-01 03:00:00 4.2 0.0 0.8 0.0
2017-01-01 04:00:00 4.4 0.0 1.0 0.0
```

このような1時間ごとのデータを1分ごとのデータに変換し、間の値は直前の値のコピー
をしたいのですが、どう書けばいいかわかりません。教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
年月日時    気温(℃)   降水量(mm) 風速(m/s) 日射量(MJ/㎡)           
2017-01-01 00:00:00 5.8 0.0 1.5 0.0
2017-01-01 00:01:00 5.8 0.0 1.5 0.0
2017-01-01 00:02:00 5.8 0.0 1.5 0.0
・・・・・
```

のようにしたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

DatetimeIndexを設定して
`resample('1min').ffill()`
するとよいかと思います。

一応サンプル。

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data="""
年月日時,気温(℃),降水量(mm),風速(m/s),日射量(MJ/㎡)
2017-01-01 00:00:00,5.8,0.0,1.5,0.0
2017-01-01 01:00:00,4.9,0.0,0.8,0.0
2017-01-01 02:00:00,4.9,0.0,1.5,0.0
2017-01-01 03:00:00,4.2,0.0,0.8,0.0
2017-01-01 04:00:00,4.4,0.0,1.0,0.0
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), parse_dates=['年月日時'], index_col='年月日時')

new_df = df.resample('1min').ffill()
print(new_df)
```

Comment: 解決しました。早速のご回答ありがとうございます。